# How can I work with only a color in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want calculate the centroid of the magenta object in a image using python.
How can I work only with magenta color object?

Here is an example image:

![this][1]

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn how to ask good questions, and (3) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert image to HSV/HSL.
2. Filter colors by magenta range.
3. Label your objects using [this function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html).
4. Use [region properties](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html) from scikit-image. You'll get centroid for each object.